# How to decorate a method in Ruby without alias_method_chain

Tags: ruby, object-model

We all know, that if the target class is composed with modules, you can just call `super` in a new module. But what if it is an ordinary method in a class?

```
class Logger
  def message(msg)
    puts msg
  end
end
```

Say, Logger is a class I can't change (e.g. it is in a gem).
And I want Logger to put a "================" line before each message. How do I do that in a **beauty** way? Inheritance? Aggregation? How?

Comment: you could open up the class or use the ol' decorator pattern to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would either perform subclassing (per @iain's answer) or a custom module inclusion in your own instances:

```
module LoggerLiner
  def message(*args)
    puts "="*15
    super
  end
end

log = Logger.new(STDOUT)
log.extend(LoggerLiner)
```

Comment: Probably, the best way if you use dependency injection in your code. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could save the original method as an unbound method object instead of saving it in an alias.

Then, you can use `define_method` with a block. The block will capture the unbound method_object in a closure, allowing you to use it in your new method, without having pollute your module/class.

The only downside is, you probably can't define a method that yields to or takes a block in this way:

```
module Mod
  unbound_method = instance_method(:original_method)
  define_method :original_method do |*args|
    #do something before
    #call the original method
    unbound_method.bind(self).call(*args)
    #do something after
  end
end
```

Comment: hi, it seems .bind method has been removed in ruby 2.4.1, do you know the current alternative?

Answer (score 2):

This may not be what you mean by "beauty" but probably the simplest way is to have, in your code somewhere:

```
class Logger
  alias message old_message
  def message(msg)
    puts "================"
    old_message(msg)
  end
end
```

Comment: `alias old_message message`, NOT `alias message old_message`

Comment: Changing common libraries like this is fine for your own code, but 'considered harmful' if your code is to be shared. Please read ["The Chainsaw Infanticide Logger Manuever"](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/tree/browse_frm/thread/aaec68ab9088e3ef/a8df09975bca1c2f?rnum=1&q=chainsaw&_done=%2Fgroup%2Fcomp.lang.ruby%2Fbrowse_frm%2Fthread%2Faaec68ab9088e3ef%3Ftvc%3D1%26q%3Dchainsaw%26#doc_233efa9b2261c825) [sic].

Comment: This *is* `alias_method_chain`. Well, almost. Your method pollutes the namespace with *one* completely useless ugly method, whereas `alias_method_chain` pollutes the namespace with *two* completely useless ugly methods.

Answer (score 2):

You could inherit from logger and use namespacing to use it:

```
class LinedLogger < Logger
  def message(*)
    puts "=" * 15
    super
  end
end
```

And when you want to use it:

```
class Post
  Logger = LinedLogger
end
```

Only within the namespace `Post`, you will get `LinedLogger` instead of `Logger`. It's a nice way of limiting your patches. It will not work globally though.

Comment: Nice. But don't you think it is a way we can call 'alias_constant'? Pretty much the same as alias_method_chain